# Vertx simple HTTP server: No response

Tags: vert.x

My vert.x version is 3.6.2. My OS is macOS (Mojave).

I created simple HTTP server:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
       HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

       Router router = Router.router(vertx);
       router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
       router.get("/produce").handler(routingContext -> {
          HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
          response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
          response.setStatusCode(200);
          response.end("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
       });

       httpServer.requestHandler(router);

       httpServer.listen(8080);
    }
```

I ran the above code from Eclipse IDE. In the Eclipse console, I noticed the following vert.x log:

> Feb 05, 2019 8:12:50 PM io.vertx.core.spi.resolver.ResolverProvider
>   INFO: Using the default address resolver as the dns resolver could not be loaded

Anyhow, I tested the above HTTP server by the browser (i.e: http://localhost:8080) but did not receive any response. I was expecting to see "Hello world".

Comment: Have you tried using `127.0.0.1:8080/produce` ? `localhost` as to be defined (I don't know how this work on macOS tho).
Also as vertx is fluent you could consider doing `routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/plain").setStatusCode(200).end("<h1>Hello world</h1>");` instead of `HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
          response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
          response.setStatusCode(200);
          response.end("<h1>Hello world</h1>");`

:)

Comment: Hi @GregoireDucharme, I followed fluent style as suggested but no luck. I did not receive any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** create maven project and it will be OK.

**Detail answer:**
I have found the answer of my question. Actually, I tried to run Vertx Http server from Eclipse. I only added few dependency Jar files to compile the Vertx projects successfully. It was not a maven project. It was an Eclipse Java project. I added vertx-core, vertx-web, netty-handler, netty-buffer, netty-resolver, netty-transport and netty-common as Eclipse User Libraries. These were not enough to run actually Vertx based Http server. During run time Vertx Http server needs more netty-* libraries.

When I imported Vertx maven project in Eclipse IDE, it worked as expected.

On the pom, I just added vertx-web but it added a number of netty-* libraries (i.e: netty-codec, netty_handler-proxy, netty-codec-socks, netty-codec-http, netty-codec-http2, netty-resolver-dns) and more as transitive dependencies.